# Objective C default init for NSObject subclass

Tags: objective-c

I'm new to Objective C and I know this is a rather trivial question.
I made a subclass of NSObject, defined some new properties and didn't define an initializer in the subclass. What happens when I call this line of code:

```
CustomClass *cl = [[CustomClass alloc] init];
```

In this line I call the superclass init method but how do the properties in my subclass get initialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All instance variables (the ones backing your properties) are initialized to default values when you create a new object instance.

All object pointers get set to `nil`. All primitive types get a value of `0` (`BOOL` is set to `NO`).

In other words, all properties in your subclass with be set to an appropriate form of "zero".

Comment: Just 2 more related questions. 1) If I define an init method in my subclass, that calls the superclass init method and then I instantiate the properties of my subclass, would I override the init method of my superclass? 2) When I define an initializer initWith: in my subclass, would I still be able to call my superclass init method?

Comment: 1) By definition, implementing a method in a subclass with the same name and parameters as a method in the superclass is overriding the method. 2) Yes, an `init...` method can call `[super init];`.